# How can I display a custom notification message with Malcom Android SDK?

Tags: android, malcom

I would like to display the notification message inside the app but not as it is displayed by the Malcom SDK by default, which displays a predefined dialog when I open the app.

Can I modify the default behavior of the library to show the message my own way?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the latest Malcom Android SDK 2.0.5 things have changed. Now you can use a `NotificationHandler` if you want to handle the notification in a custom way.

See the documentation about that:

https://github.com/MyMalcom/malcom-lib-android/blob/master/doc/Notifications.md#check-notification

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid the default behavior using the `moduleNotificationsRegister()` method with `false` in the `showAlert` param.

Then, to get the notification's message, you just need to add this on the `onCreate()` of your launch Activity:

```
String message = null;

if(getIntent()!=null && getIntent().getExtras()!=null){

    message = (String)getIntent().getExtras().get(MCMNotificationModule.ANDROID_MESSAGE_KEY);

}
```